# Why characteristics graph of Geiger Muller Counter always goes up?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics

The characteristics graph of Geiger Muller Counter always keeps going up and does not drop down . It may remain constant over an interval but does not drop down on the graph scale. Why it does not come down after going up?

Answer (score 2):

In the Geiger region an incoming charged particle produces an avalanche of charged particles which migrate across the tube and produce an easily measurable electric pulse on the electrodes.
The tube contains a halogen quenching agent which then stops the production of further charges so that one incoming particle produces one pulse.
As the voltage across the Geiger tube is increased the probability of secondary pulses being produced increases until with a sufficiently large voltage across the tube the quenching agent cannot prevent first multiple pulses and then a continuous discharge.
This shows up on the Geiger tube characteristic as first a slightly inclined plateau region and then a very large increase when the continuous discharge occurs.